# Accessing TortoiseSVN file:// repository with http:// or https://

Tags: git, svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a lot of already existed local `SVN` repositories on my `Windows` PC and `TortoiseSVN` on it. I also use `Netbeans` IDE for developing. I have problems with SVN after some updates of `Netbeans` and `TortoiseSVN`.

As I see all my projects are configured to use `file://` to access repositories, and it looks like problems are connected with using such way of repository path. Can I somehow use `http://` (`https://`) oriented paths to already existed local repositories? Or I can't and must install `VisualSVN` and create new repositories?

In best case I need some solution to resolve problem with already existed repositories and not to create new repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should install HTTP(S) capable Subversion server such as VisualSVN Server to be able to access the repositories over HTTP(S) locally or remotely.